# What parameters decide the maximum concentration achieved by a fresnel lens?

Tags: optics, lenses, renewable-energy, solar-cells

Fresnel lens can be used for concentrating sunlight for Photovoltaic. What parameters of the lens decide the maximum concentration that can be achieved using the lens.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure I understand your question correctly but the light intensity should be directly proportional to the ratio of the Fresnel lens area over the photovoltaic area. So if you have a fresnel lens wich as twice the photovoltaic area you should have twice the power. (I am assuming that the light is all colimated on the photovoltaic of course).

Not sure if photovoltaic output power varies linearly with intensity though...

Answer (score 0):

The parameter which determines the focal length of the Fresnel lens is its curvature. The working principle of a  Fresnel lens is the same as for other lenses: By passing through the lens the light acquires a position dependent phase shift. If we consider a "focusing" lens the ideal shape of the Fresnel lens is such that it produces a spherical wavefront with its center point "behind" the lens. Thus, the spherical wavefront results in a focussing beam.

The rest is analog to standard lenses. The waist of the light in the focus depends on

1. the wavelength of the light
2. the diameter of the lens (aperture)
3. the focal length of the lens.

The last one is dependent on the curvature of the lens, see lens maker's equation.